# Is the order of applying transformations in SP cryptosystems significant?

Tags: spn

[SP-cryptosystems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution%E2%80%93permutation_network) Is the order of applying transformations in SP cryptosystems matter? What will change if we first apply the P-transformation and then the S-transformation? Will cryptographic strength be less? And if yes, why?

Answer (score 1):

Let call the Substitution by $S$ and Permutation by $P$ in the Substitution Permutation Network (SPN). Let consider an SPN block cipher with $4$ rounds where $K$ represents the $\oplus$ round key.

- With $S$ applied first

  `|KSP|KSP|KSP|KSP|`

  The last $P$ has no effect on security. The attackers simply discard it. So we can consider it like;

  `|KSP|KSP|KSP|KS|`
- With $P$ applied first

  `|KPS|KPS|KPS|KPS|`

  The initial permutation has no effect in the view of the attacker. Similarly, we can consider it with some changes in the key schedule.

  `|KS|KPS|KPS|KPS|`

Now we can swap K and P that will require a change in the key schedule.

`|KSP|KSP|KSP|KS|`

That is turned into the simplified version of S applied first. Consequently, they did not differ.

Answer (score 1):

**It depends on the cryptosystem if the order of transformations matters to security.**

---

**In the example of [DES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Encryption_Standard),** we can't quite exchange S and P as considered in the question. That's because the input of S (which is 48-bit) is wider than it's output and the input and output of P (which are 32-bit). However we can exchange P and the combination of: expansion E (which input is 32-bit and output is 48-bit), XOR with subkeys (48 bits), and S (input 48-bit, output 32-bit). Then **moving P does not modify security at all**, because we can obtain such modified DES from regular DES as follows: on the 64-bit input block apply IP, P<sup>-1</sup> on both 32-bit halves, IP<sup>-1</sup>, regular DES with the unmodified key, IP<sup>-1</sup>, P on both 32-bit halves, IP.

On the other hand, there are many cases where the order of transformations matters to security. For example consider the transformations of a byte

1. Add key byte K modulo 2<sup>8</sup>
2. Apply an 8-bit substitution S-table (such at [that of AES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rijndael_S-box))
3. Subtract key byte K modulo 2<sup>8</sup>

**Here, order matters.** Any reordering moving 2 is a disaster, since the key byte becomes immaterial to the result, which is a block cipher might remove all security.